# What's needed to install a software upgrade

Tags: upgrade

Friend of mine has a Powerbook G4.
He came across some install disks for 10.4.6, in an envelope, with a bar code on the back.

He's asking me if that's all he needs to install the software.

Can anybody provide guidance on this?

Answer (score 1):

This should be all he needs, the install is only one disk. But there may be some things that hold up the install:

1. If the disk notes its for a particular machine, it does a check to see if it is the correct type of machine. There are ways to get around this, but you usually you should use the disk that is made for your machine, or a retail copy.
2. If it can't install, it shouldn't damage his current installation

If you give more information on what the disks actually say (like on the front, or a picture), it would help answer more.

Comment: +1 for particular machine. I tried installing a version of Tiger onto a friend's machine once, and it booted me out saying the hardware wasn't supported, with no loss of data to the machine.